# Converting the unit for mean and standard deviation

Tags: mean, standard-deviation, error-propagation

I have a problem and it's  been days and I couldn't find a solution

Simply what I want to do for the purpose of a research data, I have the mean and standard deviation of some measurements in diameter (mm), and I want to know how can I get the mean and standard deviation for the cross sectional area while I don't have the original data.

I think I can convert the mean using only
Pi * r^2

But for the standard deviation I have nothing

Comment: Look at some posts with the tag [tag:error-propagation].